# Reorder attribute table fields using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I'm trying to re-order my shapefile to another order that I want.
I want to keep all my data and overwrite this existent shapefile, so the shapefile would always be the way I Want.

What I'm doing is like this:

```
# Define paths to source and destination shapefiles
src_path = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "CABLE" + ".shp"
dst_path = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "CABLE_reordered" + ".shp"

# Create a vector layer object from the source shapefile
src_layer = QgsVectorLayer(src_path, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(src_path))[0], "ogr")

# Get the current layer style
#src_style = src_layer.layerStyleOverride()


# Reorder the fields as desired
field_order = ['CABLE', 'TYPE_RESEA', 'LENGTH', "REF_NRO", "EMPRISE", "ETAT_DEP", "CAPA_CABLE","MODULO","FIBRE_U","FIBRE_R","REF_INFRA"]
new_fields = QgsFields()
for field_name in field_order:
    field = src_layer.fields().field(field_name)
    new_fields.insertField(field.index(), field)

# Create a new vector layer with the reordered fields
dst_layer = QgsVectorLayer(src_layer.wkbType(), os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(dst_path))[0], "memory")
dst_layer.setCrs(src_layer.crs())
dst_layer.setFields(new_fields)

# Copy features and attributes from the source layer to the destination layer
dst_layer.startEditing()
for feat in src_layer.getFeatures():
    dst_feat = QgsFeature()
    dst_feat.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
    dst_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    dst_layer.addFeature(dst_feat)
dst_layer.commitChanges()

# Copy the style from the source layer to the destination layer
dst_layer.setLayerStyle(src_layer.renderer().layerStyle())
dst_layer.triggerRepaint()

# Save the destination layer to the shapefile and remove the source layer
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(dst_layer, dst_path, "utf-8", dst_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(src_layer)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get any error messages or what is the problem? A simpler way would be [refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisrefactorfields)

Comment: field = src_layer.fields().field(field_name)  --> where the error happens
  KeyError: 'CABLE'                                       --> The Error
  I will check that link :) Thx for the support